# Convolutions (Stats)-Summation

Tags: statistics, summation

> If $X$~Poisson$(\lambda)$ and $Y$~Poisson$(\mu)$ are independent random variables, obtain the probability function of $Z=X+Y$.

My attempt,

\begin{align}P(Z=z)&=\sum_{x=0}^{z}P(X=x)P(Y=z-x) \\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{z} \frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}\frac{\mu^{z-x}e^{-\mu}}{(z-x)!} \\
&=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}\frac{z!}{x!(z-x)!}\lambda^x\mu^{z-x} \\
&=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}\binom{z}{x}\lambda^x\mu^{z-x} \end{align}

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}\binom{z}{x}\lambda^x\mu^{z-x} &= \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}(\lambda+\mu)^z}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}\binom{z}{x}\frac{\lambda^x\mu^{z-x}}{(\lambda+\mu)^z}\\
&= \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}(\lambda+\mu)^z}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}\binom{z}{x}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^x\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{z-x}\\
&=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}(\lambda+\mu)^z}{z!}\end{align}

where the last equality is due to pmf of Binomial distribution sums to $1$.

Comment: Or just apply the Binomial Theorem.  $$\sum_{x=0}^z \binom zx \lambda^x\mu^{z-x} = (\lambda+\mu)^z$$